# How to create custom floating filter component in ag-grid that uses "inRange" filter type

Tags: filter, ag-grid-angular

I'm trying to build a custom filter component that takes a range from a text input control (e.g. '3-5') to filter the data. To do so I have modified the example given in the [ag-grid documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-floating-filter-component/#angular-floating-filters) (see code below).

When changing the type in onFloatingFilterChanged() to 'equals', 'greaterThan', 'lessThan' etc. everything works fine. But with type 'inRange' no filtering is performed.

Working example can be found on Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/oHWFIaHgWIDXP0P5

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import {
  IFloatingFilter,
  IFloatingFilterParams,
  NumberFilter,
  NumberFilterModel,
} from '@ag-grid-community/all-modules';
import { AgFrameworkComponent } from '@ag-grid-community/angular';

export interface RangeFloatingFilterParams extends IFloatingFilterParams {
  value: number;
}

@Component({
  template: `
    <input
      type="text"
      [(ngModel)]="currentValue"
      (ngModelChange)="valueChanged()"
      style="width: 70px;"
    />
  `,
})
export class RangeFloatingFilter
  implements IFloatingFilter, AgFrameworkComponent<RangeFloatingFilterParams> {
  private params: RangeFloatingFilterParams;

  public currentValue: string;

  agInit(params: RangeFloatingFilterParams): void {
    this.params = params;
    this.currentValue = '';
  }

  valueChanged() {
    let valueToUse = this.currentValue === 0 ? null : this.currentValue;
    this.params.parentFilterInstance(function(instance) {
      (<NumberFilter>instance).onFloatingFilterChanged(
        'inRange',
        valueToUse
      );
    });
  }

  onParentModelChanged(parentModel: NumberFilterModel): void {
    if (!parentModel) {
      this.currentValue = 0;
    } else {
      // note that the filter could be anything here, but our purposes we're assuming a greater than filter only,
      // so just read off the value and use that
      this.currentValue = parentModel.filter;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? Facing similar issue?

Comment: No, I haven't. I ended up with a 100% custom Filter.

Comment: Could you put up a plunkr? Trying to get something similar

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue with custom floating datepicker. I used *setModelIntoUi* method instead of *onFloatingFilterChanged*:

```
instance.setModelIntoUi({
   type: 'inRange',
   dateFrom: moment(value.min).format('YYYY-MM-DD'), // you have to use exactly this date format in order for it to work
   dateTo: moment(value.max).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
});
```

And in your case with numbers it'll be:

```
instance.setModelIntoUi({
   type: 'inRange',
   filter: value.min,
   filterTo: value.max,
});
```

**UPD:** Added this line

```
instance.onUiChanged(true);
```

after the *setModelIntoUi* method, because of the bug: filter model wasn't updating on second use.

Answer (score 0):

The code inside instance.onFloatingFilterChanged() only sets the first from value.
Use these lines below to get the correct result, as it is the only way to get inRange working.

```js
instance.setTypeFromFloatingFilter('inRange');
instance.eValueFrom1.setValue(this._input1.value);
instance.eValueTo1.setValue(this._input2.value);
instance.onUiChanged(true);
```